# RubyGems error after updating system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rvm

When trying to launch the rails console after updating my ruby setup using 'sudo gem update --system', I then try execute the rails console by issuing `rails c`

I get this error:

```
Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find json (~> 1.4) amongst [Ascii85-1.0.1, abstract-1.0.0, actionmailer-3.1.1, actionmailer-3.1.0, actionmailer-3.0.9, actionmailer-3.0.5, actionmailer-3.0.3, actionpack-3.1.1, actionpack-3.1.0, actionpack-3.0.9, actionpack-3.0.5, actionpack-3.0.3, activemodel-3.1.1, activemodel-3.1.0, activemodel-3.0.10, activemodel-3.0.9, activemodel-3.0.5, activemodel-3.0.3, activerecord-3.1.1, activerecord-3.1.0, activerecord-3.0.9, activerecord-3.0.5, activerecord-3.0.3, activeresource-3.1.1, activeresource-3.1.0, activeresource-3.0.9, activeresource-3.0.5, activeresource-3.0.3, activesupport-3.1.1, activesupport-3.1.0, activesupport-3.0.10, activesupport-3.0.9, activesupport-3.0.5, activesupport-3.0.3, addressable-2.2.6, ansi-1.3.0, arel-2.2.1, arel-2.0.10, arel-2.0.9, arel-2.0.7, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1, bcrypt-ruby-3.0.0, bcrypt-ruby-2.1.4, builder-3.0.0, builder-2.1.2, bundler-1.0.21, bundler-1.0.18, bundler-1.0.11, choices-0.2.4, cocaine-0.2.0, coffee-rails-3.1.1, coffee-rails-3.1.0, coffee-script-2.2.0, coffee-script-source-1.1.2, devise-1.4.8, devise-1.4.2, erubis-2.7.0, erubis-2.6.6, execjs-1.2.9, execjs-1.2.6, execjs-1.2.4, faraday-0.7.4, faraday-0.6.1, faraday_middleware-0.7.0, faraday_middleware-0.6.3, fastercsv-1.5.4, formtastic-2.0.2, formtastic-1.2.4, geocoder-1.0.4, geocoder-1.0.2, has_scope-0.5.1, hashie-1.1.0, hashie-1.0.0, heroku-2.7.0, hike-1.2.1, i18n-0.6.0, i18n-0.5.0, inherited_resources-1.3.0, inherited_resources-1.2.2, jquery-rails-1.0.16, jquery-rails-1.0.14, kaminari-0.12.4, launchy-2.0.5, libv8-3.3.10.2-x86_64-darwin-10, mail-2.3.0, mail-2.2.19, mail-2.2.15, mail-2.2.14, mechanize-2.0.1, mechanize-1.0.0, meta_search-1.1.1, meta_search-1.0.6, mime-types-1.16, multi_json-1.0.3, multi_xml-0.4.1, multi_xml-0.4.0, multi_xml-0.3.0, multi_xml-0.2.2, multipart-post-1.1.3, multipart-post-1.1.2, mysql-2.8.1, mysql2-0.3.7, mysql2-0.2.7, mysql2-0.2.6, net-http-digest_auth-1.1.1, net-http-persistent-2.1, net-http-persistent-2.0, net-http-persistent-1.9, nokogiri-1.5.0, nokogiri-1.4.4, orm_adapter-0.0.5, pdf-reader-0.10.0, pg-0.11.0, polyamorous-0.5.0, polyglot-0.3.2, polyglot-0.3.1, prawn-0.12.0, rack-1.3.4, rack-1.3.3, rack-1.3.2, rack-1.2.3, rack-1.2.2, rack-1.2.1, rack-cache-1.1, rack-cache-1.0.3, rack-mount-0.8.3, rack-mount-0.6.14, rack-mount-0.6.13, rack-ssl-1.3.2, rack-test-0.6.1, rack-test-0.5.7, rails-3.1.1, rails-3.1.0, rails-3.0.9, rails-3.0.5, rails-3.0.3, railties-3.1.1, railties-3.1.0, railties-3.0.9, railties-3.0.5, railties-3.0.3, rake-0.9.2, rake-0.8.7, rake-0.8.7, rash-0.3.1, rash-0.3.0, rdoc-3.10, rdoc-3.9.4, rdoc-3.9.2, responders-0.6.4, rest-client-1.6.7, rubygems-update-1.8.11, rubygems-update-1.8.10, rubygems-update-1.7.2, rubygems-update-1.7.1, rubygems-update-1.6.2, rubyzip-0.9.4, sass-3.1.10, sass-3.1.7, sass-rails-3.1.4, sass-rails-3.1.2, sass-rails-3.1.0, simple_oauth-0.1.5, sprockets-2.0.2, sprockets-2.0.0, sqlite3-1.3.4, term-ansicolor-1.0.6, therubyracer-0.9.4, thor-0.14.6, tilt-1.3.3, treetop-1.4.10, treetop-1.4.9, ttfunk-1.0.3, ttfunk-1.0.2, turn-0.8.2, twitter-1.7.1, twitter-1.4.1, tzinfo-0.3.30, tzinfo-0.3.29, tzinfo-0.3.26, tzinfo-0.3.24, uglifier-1.0.3, warden-1.0.6, warden-1.0.5, webrobots-0.0.12, webrobots-0.0.11] (Gem::LoadError)
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1932:in `block in traverse'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1931:in `each'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1931:in `traverse'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:465:in `block in find_in_unresolved_tree'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:463:in `reverse_each'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:463:in `find_in_unresolved_tree'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:47:in `require'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/script_rails_loader.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/cli.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/rails-3.1.1/bin/rails:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rails:19:in `load'
from /Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @AshleyWilliams yes I have run that. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try adding `gem "json", "~> 1.4"` directly in your Gemfile (and running `bundle install`). Does `rails server` work okay, is it just `rails console`?

Comment: @AshleyWilliams that did the trick. Why is it requiring it when I'm not actually utilising it?

Comment: I guess it's easier than lazily loading it. Most apps use it anyway. I've added my comment as an answer below so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

what do you get when you try to list your gems.. is json >=  1.4 there?

e.g.:

```
> gem list json

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

json (1.6.1, 1.5.4, 1.5.3, 1.5.1, 1.4.2)
json_pure (1.6.1, 1.5.4, 1.5.3)
```

if you use RVM gemsets, you may want to list them also, to check if your default gemset has changed:

```
rvm gemset list
```

---

EDIT:  **Mystery Solved!** :-)

**you accidentially installed your gems with sudo -- but you have RVM installed for your user account!**

When you have RVM installed for an individual user, it's generally not a good idea to do sudo gem install ... , but you should install the gems just for the local user and let RVM manage them for whatever Ruby version you are using.

If you still install with sudo, RVM will not find the gems, because they are stored in a different location, outside of RVM, and not searched by RVM...!  Looks like that's the case you experienced.

Check this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/200-rails-3-beta-and-rvm

if you're using Rails:
 - **edit your Gemfile** and add the json dependency , then run `bundle install`

if you're just using Ruby by itself, or an old version or Ruby:
 - run `gem install json` in the shell

With newer Ruby versions you should not manually install the gems

Comment: when I run `gem list json` it doesn't appear... even though it has definitely been installed `sudo gem install json`. When running `rvm gemset list` it produces the following: `gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p136 (found in /Users/elliottheis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136)`
global. Any ideas?

Comment: looks like you accidentally used 'sudo' .. you shouldn't use it when you have RVM installed for your local user account

Comment: @Tilo would it be worth removing the rvm installed version of ruby, and starting again as I have a feeling that I've done that for a couple of the gems... Are you able to give some pointers as to how I can achieve that (i'm running OS X Lion)?

Comment: I'd keep RVM, the RVM installed Ruby version, amd the RVM installed Gems -- and would delete the sudo installed Gems with "sudo gem uninstallXYZ"

Comment: @Eliot better to delete the sudo installed Gems! and then just install them as described above - as your user

Comment: you can run 'sudo gem list ' to see which Gems need to be uninstalled -- then install them with 'gem install'

Answer (score 2):

Add `gem "json", "~> 1.4"` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 2):

Also

You *only* use the sudo command during the install process. In Multi-User configurations, any operations which require sudo access must use the rvmsudo command which preserves the RVM environment and passes this on to sudo. There are very few cases where rvmsudo is required once the core install is completed, except for when updating RVM itself. There is never a reason to use sudo post-install. Once users added to the 'rvm' group have logged out, then back in to gain rvm group membership, rvmsudo should only be needed for updating RVM itself with

```
rvmsudo rvm get head
```

*Please* read the https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/support/troubleshooting/ page The installer page also details this for new installations. You will need to remove your existing installation and redo it in order to properly reconfigure the permissions. In the future, **never** user *sudo* when working on your RVM installation, *except* when installing. *Any* other commands will not require sudo use *except* for

```
rvmsudo rvm get head
```

to update your installation. If the users are properly placed in the rvm group as detailed on the site, you will have no need to use sudo at all, and rvmsudo **only** for updating.

Also, RVM does not manage the system installed ruby *at all*! We do provide the use of

```
rvm use system
```

in order to give a natural way to switch between RVM controlled rubies, and the system. Your package manager, or lack thereof for OS X, is responsible for managing your system installed ruby and is outside the control of RVM 100%.