# Frank setup for iOS not working

Tags: testing, cucumber, frank

I am trying to setup frank-cucumber for iOS, I am using [this tutorial](http://blog.thepete.net/blog/2012/06/24/writing-your-first-frank-test/) and I am stuck at frank setup.  I navigate to my iOS app, then do a `sudo gem install frank-cucumber` and that works fine.  I then enter `frank setup` and it gives me this: `in activate: can't activate i18n (= 0.6.1, runtime) for ["activesupport-3.2.13", "xcodeproj-0.5.5", "frank-cucumber-1.1.9.pre1"], already activated i18n-0.6.4 for ["frank-cucumber-1.1.9.pre1"] (Gem::LoadError)`

Should I do something with `i18n`?

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308070

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7786543

Comment: Thanks @Robert Harvey for the answers.  I have another problem though, now it's complaining that I need i18n: in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem i18n (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)

Comment: I had uninstalled i18n then tried frank setup

Comment: Try installing the correct version of the i18n gem separately.  I would have expected the frank-cucumber class to do that automatically, but I guess not.

Comment: Okay, that didn't work, maybe I'll uninstall i18n and frank-cucumber, then re-install frank-cucumber.

Comment: Wow, I have 3 version of frank-cucumber.  That's probably a problem.

Comment: Dang, still not working.  Gives me a similar error: `in report_activate_error: RubyGem version error: i18n(0.6.4 not = 0.6.1) (Gem::LoadError)`

Comment: Did you completely uninstall all versions of i18n and frank-cucumber?

Comment: Yes I did uninstall all versions of both